# Efficiently calculating totals from a file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm reading a file and turning each line within it into a class, let's call it `Record`, and returning each `Record` as it is read using `IEnumerable<Record>` and `yield return`.

Because of this I only start actually performing these reads whenever I do an operation on the enumeration, such as performing a sum on it or iterating through it with a `foreach`.

I do need to go through each record and then translate that into a database, but due to database design before my time I need the totals on *each record* in the database, so I need these totals before I start translating them into my database.

At the moment I have five separate `.Count()` or `.Sum()` operations on my enumeration before I start iterating the enumeration (example `int i = records.Sum(r => r.SomeField)` or `int j = records.Count(r => r.IsSomethingTrue)`). Each one of those counts or sums will loop through the entire file to calculate each one separately. I'm not really happy with this behaviour and would like to find a more efficient way of doing this.

I am using .NET 3.5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you considered a stored procedure?

Comment: The totals are from a file, not from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efficiency is not a strength of LINQ... You need to replace some LINQ things with manual loops here.

You seem to need two passes over the data. One for aggregation:

```
var sum = 0; //etc.
foreach (var item in items) {
 //compute all 5 aggregates here
}
```

And then one to translate the data:

```
items.Select(item => Translate(item, aggregates))
```

Whether you should buffer `items` (for example using `ToList`) or not depends on whether available memory can hold those items or not.

You can use `Aggregate` to perform all 5 aggregations in one pass but that's not better than a loop in any way. It's slower, far more code and the code arguably is illegible.

Comment: Is Aggregate that slow? You make a good point about legibility though.

Comment: @Logan slow is relative. It's 2 vcalls and one delegate call per iteration. The JIT does nothing to make this fast. All very indirect code. It depends on how slow your aggregation is. If it is just 5 additions then you can easily loose 2-3x compared to a loop. The old JIT and RyuJIT are appealingly bad with struct handling as well. Expect many loads and stores to memory. No register use.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if the volumes I'm dealing with will take much of a hit on this, but I'm trying to account for growth as well (which is why I'm not just throwing everything into memory and working from that). I guess the loop is the better option purely from the readability standpoint. Thanks.

Comment: @Logan yeah, it's just so simple. If you want to make this an expression like an Aggregate call is (and a loop is not) then you can put it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own `struct` to calculate a few values at the single pass through an enumerable object.

```
public struct ComplexAccumulator
{
    public int TotalSumField { get; set; }

    public int CountSomethingTrue { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `Aggreagate` extension method to accumulate values:

```
records.Aggregate(default(ComplexAccumulator), (a, r) => new ComplexAccumulator
{
    TotalSumFiled = a.TotalSumField + r.SumField,
    CountSomethingTrue = a.CountSomethingTrue + r.IsSomethingTrue ? 1 : 0,
});
```

Instead of the `struct` you could use suitable `Tuple` instance, f.e. something like `Tuple<int, int, int>`.

Comment: I was thinking Aggregate was the right thing to use but I wasn't sure how, I'll give this a shot, thanks.